# Is It possible to add custom block in CMS pages?

Tags: magento2

I made an extension and place block for specific CMS pages, How Can I Place my block in CMS pages?
I am trying to enable extension from admin and select specific CMS pages then block should be displayed.

```
    <referenceBlock name="cms_page">
        <block name="pindemocms" class="Kitesky\PinterestBlock\Block\Display\Display" template="Kitesky_PinterestBlock::getpin.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="pintresetbck" xsi:type="string">pintresetbck</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can able to call block in any `cms page` in `admin edit the cms page`.

And go to the `Design` >>  `Layout Update XML`: add code and `Save` it.

```
<referenceBlock name="cms_page">
    <block name="pindemocms" class="Kitesky\PinterestBlock\Block\Display\Display" template="Kitesky_PinterestBlock::getpin.phtml">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="pintresetbck" xsi:type="string">pintresetbck</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
```